# Prove that $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\sin(\tan x) dx\geq \frac{\pi^2}{32}$ and $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\tan(\sin x)dx\geq \frac{\pi^2}{18}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $A_1=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\sin(\tan x) dx$ and $A_2=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\tan(\sin x)dx$.

We are required to prove that $A_1\geq \frac{\pi^2}{32}$ and $A_2\geq \frac{\pi^2}{18}$

**My Attempt**

On checking with calculator I find that both statements hold true. But proving it is giving contradictory results.

Now we know that $\tan x>x$

$\Rightarrow \sin(\tan x)>\sin x$

$\Rightarrow \sin(\tan x)>x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-...$

$\Rightarrow \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\sin(\tan x)dx>\left|\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-...\right|_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}$

$A_1>\frac{\pi^2}{32}-...$

Here I find a bit of inconsistency. The RHS of above inequality is clearly smaller than $\frac{\pi^2}{32}$

Using the fact that $\sin(\tan x)>\sin x$ and going by the same approach as above I get

$A_2>\frac{\pi^2}{18}-...$

Once again RHS is clearly smaller than $\frac{\pi^2}{18}$.

Can there be a better way to get to the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly believe the crucial part is to notice that $\sin(\tan x ) \geq x$ for $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{4}$. Indeed, observe the function $f(x) = \sin(\tan x )$ for $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{4}$, this has a derivative $$\cos(\tan x ) \sec^2(x) = \frac{\cos(\tan x)}{\cos^2 x}.$$ I claim that $f'(x) > 1$ for $0 < x < \pi /4$ (this appears to be the case when plotting the graph but I have not been able to finish this part of the proof yet ...) Notice on the plot that $f(x) > x$ for the desired interval; a bound much more tightly met than $f(x) > \sin x$. Also remark that $f'(x) > 1$ for $0 < x < \pi /4$.
[image: plotting f(x)]

If this is true, then applying the Mean Value Theorem to $f$ on $(0,x)$ yields a $0 < c < x$ such that $$\frac{\sin(\tan x) - 0}{x - 0} = \cos(\tan c) \sec^2(c) > 1$$ proving the inequality.

Then your integration inequality follows with a similar argument as you gave, but without the higher order terms. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The first inequality follows directly from the more general
$$\tag1
\int_0^x\sin(\tan t)\,dt\geq\frac12\,x^2,\qquad\qquad 0\leq x\leq\arctan\frac{3\pi}4.
$$

First, we integrate
$$\tag2
\int_0^x\sin(\tan t)\,dt=\int_0^{\tan x}\frac{\sin t}{1+t^2}\,dt\geq\int_0^{\tan x}\sin t\,dt=1-\cos\tan x\geq\frac{x^2}2.
$$
The steps above are

- substitute $u=\tan t$
- use $1+t^2\geq1$

The non-trivial part is the inequality
$$\tag3
1-\cos\tan x\geq\frac {x^2}2,\qquad\qquad 0\leq x\leq \arctan\frac{3\pi}4.
$$

The proof I have of this inequality is not pretty, so I'll be happy to be shown an improvement. I will use repeatedly the fact that

> $$\tag4
> \text{if }f(0)=g(0)\ \text{ and }f'\leq g',\ \text{ then }f(x)=\int_0^xf'\leq\int_0^xg'=g(x). 
> $$

Now $(4)$ tells us that we can show $(3)$ by instead showing that
$$\tag5
\frac{\sin\tan x}{\cos^2 x}\geq x,\qquad\qquad 0\leq x\leq \arctan\frac{3\pi}4.
$$
Another application of $(4)$ now reduces the problem to showing that
$$\tag6
\frac{\cos\tan x+2\sin x\ \cos x\ \sin\tan x}{\cos^4 x}\geq1,\qquad\qquad 0\leq x\leq \arctan\frac{3\pi}4. 
$$
Note that every quantity involved in $(6)$ is non-negative. When $0\leq x\leq\frac\pi4$, the inequality $(6)$ follows if we show that $$\tag7\frac{\cos\tan x}{\cos^4x}\geq1\qquad\qquad 0\leq x\leq\frac\pi4.$$ Putting $t=\tan x$ and noting that $\cos x=(1+\tan^2x)^{1/2}$ for $0\leq x\leq\frac\pi4$, the inequality $(7)$ looks like
$$\tag8
(1+t^2)^2\cos t\geq1,\qquad\qquad 0\leq t\leq 1.
$$
I don't have a fancy way of checking this inequality, but one can see that the left-hand-side is positive, it is $0$ at $0$, its derivative is positive at $0$, and the first positive zero is $>1$. All this together justifies $(8)$ and hence $(7)$.

Going back to $(6)$, when $\frac\pi4\leq x\leq\arctan\frac{3\pi}4$, we have that $1\leq\tan x\leq\frac{3\pi}4 $ and $\cos x\leq\cos\frac\pi4=\frac1{\sqrt2}$. Then $\sin x\geq\frac1{\sqrt2}$, $\sin\tan x\geq\frac1{\sqrt2}$, and so
$$\tag9
\frac{2\sin x\ \cos x\ \sin\tan x}{\cos^4 x}
=\frac{2\sin x\ \sin\tan x}{\cos^3 x}\geq 4\sqrt2\frac1{\sqrt2}\,\frac1{\sqrt2}=2\sqrt2>1.
$$
Now $(9)$ and $(7)$ together justify $(6)$, and we are done.